# Issue in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm getting below error while running a shell script. Kindly help [intention for the script is to check whether current OS version (RHEL/CentOS) is less that 7 or not]

================================== ERROR ==============================

```
./test.sh: line 5: 7]: No such file or directory
PHP 5.4 will be installed by default
```

=======================================================================

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script Name: test.sh

VERSION=`cat /etc/redhat-release|awk '{print $4}'|cut -d "." -f1`
if [ "$VERSION" < "7" ]
then
echo "PHP 5.4 need to be installed separately"

    else
    echo "PHP 5.4 will be installed by default"

fi`
```

Comment: it is hard to understand your question. please rewrite it so we could see the script properly.

Comment: what is the (') apostrophe before "#!/bin/bash" ??

Comment: Use `-lt` instead of `<`. Also use `[[]]` instead of `[]` to prevent the shell from interpreting `<` and `>` as file descriptors/operators.

Comment: @stzahi  that was (`) which came by default while pasting the code on forum.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` (`test`) builtin (and external one) (and also keyword `[[`) does not support `<`, `>` style arithmetic comparisons. You need the arithmetic comparison operator `((` or use `-lt` (less than):

```
(( "$VERSION" < 7 ))
[ "$VERSION" -lt 7 ]
```

Comment: Thank You so much to make me understand where i was wrong. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script Name: test.sh

VERSION=$(awk '{print $7}' /etc/redhat-release|cut -d "." -f1)
if [ "$VERSION" -lt 7 ];then

    echo "PHP 5.4 need to be installed separately"

else
    echo "PHP 5.4 will be installed by default"

fi
```

Note:

1. Avoid using backtick. you can use var=$(command)
2. For integer comparison , use -lt ,-gt,-eq ,-ne for comparison.
3. Check your code syntax at [Shell-check](http://www.shellcheck.net/#). You could have solved this yourself.

Comment: Some explanation would be useful for OP.